# How to assign a date variable from form1 to form2 in datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms

In Section 28 of my source code I am assigning, the database field of date (car_completiondate) to a variable mcompdate and also to label4.Text. I want to use mcompdate or label4.Text in the second form, please advise how to?

```
// 28
// var mcompdate = (DateTime)reader1["car_completiondate"];
// label4.Text = (String.Format("{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(reader1[28]).ToShortDateString()));
label4.Text = (Convert.ToDateTime(reader1[28]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
DateTime mcompdate = DateTime.Parse(label4.Text);
                
// DateTime mcompdate = DateTime.ParseExact(label4.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way is to make a field in one Form and access it in the other Form. For example

Field in second Form:

```
public DateTime date { private get; set; }
```

Now in first Form you just have to set the value of the date field `form2_name.date = mcompdate` and then in the second form you can use however you like. If you want to performs more operations than you can also use a public method just as explained.

Comment: form2_name.setValue(mcompdate) , in the program mcompdate gets red underline

Comment: cddate.Value = Form3.mcompdate;  --> error below System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value of '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.
Parameter name: Value

Comment: @Siraj sorry that was a typing mistake, I have corrected it now.